# GitLab merge request into GitHub?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

My code is on GitHub, but I use GitLab CI. I set up GitLab CI/CD external repo and linked my GitHub. I set up GitLab Pull mirroring to get changes from my GitHub.

Since my CI is on GitLab, I am working on setting up review deployments and automated merge requests here.

Is it possible/appropriate to handle merge requests on GitLab, then persist to GitHub? Do I just need to set up a Push mirror from GitLab to GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible/appropriate to handle merge requests on GitLab, then persist to GitHub?

Yes, with two caveats:

1. A GitLab Merge Request will be mirrored (through [Repository mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/)) as a simple branch on GitHub. Said branch won't have a "Pull Request" status on it.
2. The comments associated to a merge request (from "[Merge Request Commit Discussions](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/12/22/gitlab-10-3-released/#merge-request-commit-discussions) " from [GitLab 10.3](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/01/04/comment-on-commits-feature-tutorial/)) would not be replicated in a GitHub issue.

Comment: Great to know! I just set up repository mirroring (push), created the GitLab merge request, accepted it, hit the refresh button to sync the mirror, and there it is on GitHub! I was having some trouble at first because I didn't see "Merge Requests" in the menu of my GitLab, but discovered it is disabled by default, and had to be enabled in Settings.